# how can I change display name on View in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have a React Native project. At first the view has `style = {{ Display:null }}` but I want to change this to `style = {{Display:'none'}}`.

How can I do that?

```
<View style={{Dispaly:null}} >
<TouchableOpacity onPress={???}>
<Text>hide</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Comment: you can simply use [state](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html)

Comment: Try `View.displayName = //Some Name`

Comment: And it's not a valid style, either `Dispaly` or `Display` won't work with style of `<View />`

Comment: Is it that you need to hide/show this view onPress ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many way to do it :

Example 1)

```
constructor(){
   super()
   this.state = {
      visibility : 'flex'
   } 
}

render(){
  return (
    <View style={{display:this.state.visibility}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.setState({visibility:'none'})}>
      <Text>hide</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

When you press the button , visibility change from 'flex' to 'none'.

Note that the default value for this.state.visibility is 'flex'. According to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#display) display only supports 'flex' and 'none'.

Example 2)

```
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
          visibility : true
    }
  }

  myView(){
    return(
      <View >
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.setState({visibility:false})}>
        <Text>hide</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
       {this.state.visibility == true ?this.myView() :null}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

In this case this.state.visibility is a boolean.Its default value is true. Inside the render methods we check its value. If it is true we call the method myView() else we do nothing